# Simple peer and socket.io keeps sending back and forth requests 100s of times. Unable to establish signal connections

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io, webrtc, simple-peer

I am trying to establish a connection between the two different users on the server. Every time a users joins the room he gets the info about the socket.ids of other users in the room. What they try and do is the new user creates an initiator peer and sends a signal . Which the other peer accepts for some reason they both keep sending each other back and forth requests and no one access each other requests this is what is happening.
[A picture of the backend console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Qpvq.png)

```
createPeer = (userToSignal, callerId, stream) => {
    console.log('create peer called', userToSignal);
    const peer = new Peer({
        initiator: true,
        trickle: false,
        stream: stream
    })

    peer.on('signal', signal => {
        console.log('sending a signal to server')
        this.socket.emit('sending signal', {
            'userToSignal': userToSignal,
            'callerId': callerId,
            'signal': signal
        });
    });

    return peer;
}

addPeer = (incomingSignal, callerId, stream) => {
    console.log('Add peer called', callerId);
    const peer = new Peer({
        initiator: false,
        trickle: false,
        stream: stream
    });

    peer.signal(JSON.stringify(incomingSignal));

    peer.on('signal', signal =>{
        console.log('returning a signal to : ', callerId)
        this.socket.emit('returning signal', {
            'signal': signal,
            'callerId': callerId
        });
    });

    return peer;
}

joinCall = () => {
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: false, audio: true }).then(stream => {
        console.log(this.socket.id);
        this.socket.emit('join call', this.state.id, this.state.userName);
        console.log('Join Call Called')
        this.socket.on('all users', (usersInThisRoom) => {
            console.log('all users ', usersInThisRoom);
            const peers = [];
            usersInThisRoom.forEach(user => {
                console.log('for each called')
                const peer = this.createPeer(user['id'], this.socket.id, stream);
                peers.push({
                    'peerId' : user['id'],
                    'peer': peer 
                })
            });
            this.peersRefs = peers;
            this.setState({peersRefs : this.peersRefs});
        });

        this.socket.on('user joined', payload => {
            console.log('new user has joined', payload['callerId']);
            const peer = this.addPeer(payload['signal'], payload['callerId'], stream);
            this.peersRefs.push({
                'peerId': payload['callerId'],
                'peer': peer
            })
            this.setState({'peersRefs': this.peersRefs});
        });

        this.socket.on('receiving returned signal', payload => {
            console.log('returned signal recieved ', payload.id)
            const peerToSignal = this.peersRefs.find(peer => peer['peerId'] === payload.id)
            peerToSignal['peer'].signal(JSON.stringify(payload.signal));
        });
    });

    console.log('joining')     
}
```

This is my front end code ^^

```
// Changes start
socket.on('join call', (roomId, name) => {
    console.log('New User ', name)

    SessionModel.findById(roomId, (err, session, callback) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        let users = session.usersInCall;
        if (users.length === 10) {
            return;
        }
        let userObject = { 'id' : socket.id, 'name' : name};
        users.push(userObject);
        SessionModel.findOneAndUpdate({_id: roomId}, {usersInCall: users}, {
            new: true
        }, 
        (err) => {
            if (err) throw err
        });

        const usersInThisRoom = users.filter(user => {
            return user['id'] !== socket.id;
        });
        console.log(usersInThisRoom);
        socket.emit("all users", usersInThisRoom);

    })
})

socket.on('sending signal', payload => {
    console.log('Sending Signal',payload['userToSignal'] );

    io.to(payload['userToSignal']).emit('user joined', {
        'signal': payload['signal'],
        'callerId': payload['callerId']
    });
})

socket.on('returning signal', payload => {
    console.log('forwarding signal ',payload['callerId'])
    io.to(payload['callerId']).emit('receiving returned signal', {
        'signal' : payload['signal'],
        'id': socket.id
    });
})
```

This is my back end code ^^^

Answer (score 0):

Try putting all ur socketio listners inside useEffect

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have created an infinite loop. Form the backend logs is
"forwarding signal ......" should have only be printed once. As the client socket is emitting the event `returning signal` twice.
Adding the client console logs would have helped in debugging.